# Solve resolves symbolic linear system in 20 seconds, LinearSolve just grinds on and on

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, linear-algebra, symbolic

I am repeatedly solving (related) systems of symbolic linear equations. 
*Solve* has worked reliably, but I expected *LinearSolve* to be faster. 
I ran into this case, which *Solve* resolves in ~20 seconds, while *LinearSolve* seems to be stumped.  It just keeps running...

**Comment added later**:  C.E. says *LinearSolve* gives him an answer in 35 seconds. I let it run for several hours on two different machines and ... nothing.  Interesting observation, though: The final equation is complicated, but not complicating -- it is a long involved expression defining a variable that appears in no other equation. Without that variable and equation, *LinearSolve* finds an answer in 8 or 9 seconds (hallelujah!) and it is easy to back substitute to find this last variable. Odd that something like that should so confound LinearSolve.

The system of equations for *Solve*: (Sorry, this is the smallest example I've found) has the 14 variables:

```
variables = {x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5], x[6], z[2], z[3], z[4], z[5], w[3],     
             w[4], w[5], w[6], y[3]};
```

and the 14 equations

```
equations = {1/r[2] - (2 E^(-((2 M r[2])/v^2)) r[2] x[2])/v^2 == 
               0, 
            -s[3]/r[3] + s[3]/r[4] + S[4]/r[3] -
             S[4]/r[4] + (-E^(-((2 r[3] s[3])/v^2)) + 
             E^(-((2 r[3] S[4])/v^2))) x[3] - 
             (-E^(-((2 r[4] s[3])/v^2)) + E^(-((2 r[4] S[4])/v^2))) x[4] == 0, 
             -s[4]/r[4] + s[4]/r[5] + S[5]/r[4] - 
              S[5]/r[5] + (-E^(-((2 r[4] s[4])/v^2)) + 
              E^(-((2 r[4] S[5])/v^2))) x[4] - 
              (-E^(-((2 r[5] s[4])/v^2)) + E^(-((2 r[5] S[5])/v^2))) x[5] == 0, 
             -s[5]/r[5] + s[5]/r[6] + S[6]/r[5] - 
              S[6]/r[6] + (-E^(-((2 r[5] s[5])/v^2)) + 
              E^(-((2 r[5] S[6])/v^2))) x[5] - 
              (-E^(-((2 r[6] s[5])/v^2)) + E^(-((2 r[6] S[6])/v^2))) x[6] == 0, 
              1/r[6] - (2 r[6] x[6])/v^2 == 0, 
              1/r[2] - 1/r[6] - (2 E^(-((2 r[2] s[2])/v^2)) r[2] x[2])/v^2 + 
             (2 E^(-((2 r[6] s[2])/v^2)) r[6] x[6])/v^2 - (h z[2])/r[2] + 
             (4 E^(-((2 r[2] s[2])/v^2)) Cee[2] r[2]^2 z[2])/v^4 + 
             (h z[2])/r[6] - (4 E^(-((2 r[6] s[2])/v^2)) Cee[6] r[6]^2 z[2])/v^4 == 0, 
              1/r[3] - 1/r[4] - (2 E^(-((2 r[3] s[3])/v^2)) r[3] x[3])/v^2 +
             (2 E^(-((2 r[4] s[3])/v^2)) r[4] x[4])/v^2 - (h z[3])/r[3] + 
             (4 E^(-((2 r[3] s[3])/v^2)) Cee[3] r[3]^2 z[3])/v^4 + 
             (h z[3])/r[4] - (4 E^(-((2 r[4] s[3])/v^2)) Cee[4] r[4]^2 z[3])/v^4 == 0, 
              1/r[4] - 1/r[5] - (2 E^(-((2 r[4] s[4])/v^2)) r[4] x[4])/v^2 + 
             (2 E^(-((2 r[5] s[4])/v^2)) r[5] x[5])/v^2 - (h z[4])/r[4] + 
             (4 E^(-((2 r[4] s[4])/v^2)) Cee[4] r[4]^2 z[4])/v^4 + 
             (h z[4])/r[5] - (4 E^(-((2 r[5] s[4])/v^2)) Cee[5] r[5]^2 z[4])/v^4 == 0, 
             1/r[5] - 1/r[6] - (2 E^(-((2 r[5] s[5])/v^2)) r[5] x[5])/v^2 + 
            (2 E^(-((2 r[6] s[5])/v^2)) r[6] x[6])/v^2 - (h z[5])/r[5] +
            (4 E^(-((2 r[5] s[5])/v^2)) Cee[5] r[5]^2 z[5])/v^4 + 
            (h z[5])/r[6] - (4 E^(-((2 r[6] s[5])/v^2)) Cee[6] r[6]^2 z[5])/v^4 == 0,
           -(1/r[2]) + 1/r[3] + (h w[3])/r[2] - 
            (4 E^(-((2 r[2] S[3])/v^2)) Cee[2] r[2]^2 w[3])/v^4 - 
            (h w[3])/r[3] + (4 E^(-((2 r[3] S[3])/v^2)) Cee[3] r[3]^2 w[3])/v^4 + 
            (2 E^(-((2 r[2] S[3])/v^2)) r[2] x[2])/v^2 - 
            (2 E^(-((2 r[3] S[3])/v^2)) r[3] x[3])/v^2 == 0,
           -(1/r[3]) + 1/r[4] + (h w[4])/r[3] - 
            (4 E^(-((2 r[3] S[4])/v^2)) Cee[3] r[3]^2 w[4])/v^4 - 
            (h w[4])/r[4] + (4 E^(-((2 r[4] S[4])/v^2)) Cee[4] r[4]^2 w[4])/v^4 + 
            (2 E^(-((2 r[3] S[4])/v^2)) r[3] x[3])/v^2 - 
            (2 E^(-((2 r[4] S[4])/v^2)) r[4] x[4])/v^2 == 0, 
            -(1/r[4]) + 1/r[5] + (h w[5])/r[4] - 
             (4 E^(-((2 r[4] S[5])/v^2)) Cee[4] r[4]^2 w[5])/v^4 - 
             (h w[5])/r[5] + (4 E^(-((2 r[5] S[5])/v^2)) Cee[5] r[5]^2 w[5])/v^4 + 
             (2 E^(-((2 r[4] S[5])/v^2)) r[4] x[4])/v^2 - 
             (2 E^(-((2 r[5] S[5])/v^2)) r[5] x[5])/v^2 == 0, 
            -(1/r[5]) + 1/r[6] + (h w[6])/r[5] - 
             (4 E^(-((2 r[5] S[6])/v^2)) Cee[5] r[5]^2 w[6])/v^4 - 
             (h w[6])/r[6] + (4 E^(-((2 r[6] S[6])/v^2)) Cee[6] r[6]^2 w[6])/v^4 + 
             (2 E^(-((2 r[5] S[6])/v^2)) r[5] x[5])/v^2 - 
             (2 E^(-((2 r[6] S[6])/v^2)) r[6] x[6])/v^2 == 0, 
             y[3] == 1/2 (-2 (-E^(-((2 r[2] s[2])/v^2)) + 
                     E^(-((2 r[2] S[3])/v^2))) x[2] - 
                     ((-h v^2 + 2 r[2] (-t + p r[2]) + 
                        h r[2] (s[2] + S[3])) (-w[3] + z[2]))/r[2]^2 - 
                        2 Cee[2] (-((2 E^(-((2 r[2] S[3])/v^2)) r[2] w[3])/v^2) + 
                     (2 E^(-((2 r[2] s[2])/v^2)) r[2] z[2])/v^2) - 
                     ((s[2] - S[3]) (-2 r[2] + h r[2] (w[3] + z[2])))/r[2]^2) + 
                     1/2 (2 (-E^(-((2 r[3] s[3])/v^2)) + 
                              E^(-((2 r[3] S[3])/v^2))) x[3] + 
                     ((-h v^2 + 2 r[3] (-t + p r[3]) + 
                        h r[3] (s[3] + S[3])) (-w[3] + z[3]))/r[3]^2 + 
                      2 Cee[3] (-((2 E^(-((2 r[3] S[3])/v^2)) r[3] w[3])/v^2) + 
                     (2 E^(-((2 r[3] s[3])/v^2)) r[3] z[3])/v^2) + 
                     ((s[3] - S[3]) (-2 r[3] + h r[3] (w[3] + z[3])))/r[3]^2) + 
                 1/2 (2 (E^(-((2 r[4] s[3])/v^2)) - E^(-((2 r[4] s[4])/v^2))) x[4] - 
                 ((-h v^2 + 2 r[4] (-t + p r[4]) + 
                    h r[4] (s[3] + s[4])) (z[3] - z[4]))/r[4]^2 + 
                    2 Cee[4] (-((2 E^(-((2 r[4] s[3])/v^2)) r[4] z[3])/v^2) + 
                 (2 E^(-((2 r[4] s[4])/v^2)) r[4] z[4])/v^2) - 
                 ((s[3] - s[4]) (-2 r[4] + h r[4] (z[3] + z[4])))/r[4]^2) + 
                   1/2 (2 (-E^(-((2 r[6] s[2])/v^2)) + 
                            E^(-((2 r[6] s[5])/v^2))) x[6] + 
                       ((-h v^2 + 2 r[6] (-t + p r[6]) + 
                          h r[6] (s[2] + s[5])) (z[2] - z[5]))/r[6]^2 + 
                   2 Cee[6] ((2 E^(-((2 r[6] s[2])/v^2)) r[6] z[2])/v^2 - 
                  (2 E^(-((2 r[6] s[5])/v^2)) r[6] z[5])/v^2) + 
                  ((s[2] - s[5]) (-2 r[6] + h r[6] (z[2] + z[5])))/r[6]^2) + 
                  1/2 (2 (E^(-((2 r[5] s[4])/v^2)) - 
                          E^(-((2 r[5] s[5])/v^2))) x[5] - 
                  ((-h v^2 + 2 r[5] (-t + p r[5]) + 
                     h r[5] (s[4] + s[5])) (z[4] - z[5]))/r[5]^2 + 
                  2 Cee[5] (-((2 E^(-((2 r[5] s[4])/v^2)) r[5] z[4])/v^2) + 
                 (2 E^(-((2 r[5] s[5])/v^2)) r[5] z[5])/v^2) - 
                 ((s[4] - s[5]) (-2 r[5] + h r[5] (z[4] + z[5])))/r[5]^2)};
```

It takes 20 seconds or so, but

```
sol = Solve[equations, variables];
```

produces the correct answer.

In an effort to speed things along, *ToMatrix* and *GetRHS* converts this to a linear system *matrix.variables == rhs*

```
ToMatrix[equations_, variables_] :=  
        Map[Function[poly, Map[Coefficient[poly, #] &, variables]], 
            Map[(#[[1]] - #[[2]]) &, equations]]

GetRHS[equations_, variables_] :=  
      Transpose[{Simplify[Map[(#[[2]] - #[[1]]) &, equations] + 
                ToMatrix[equations, variables].variables]}]
```

So we can solve the system with *LinearSolve*

```
matrix = ToMatrix[equations, variables];
rhs = GetRHS[equations, variables];
lsol = LinearSolve[matrix, rhs];
```

Sadly, it's still running. The only reason I can think of is *LinearSolve* is spending enormous time on *ZeroTest*. But don't the two use the same test?

Comment: For me, `Solve` takes 21 seconds and `LinearSolve` takes 35 seconds. So `LinearSolve` is slower, but not that much slower. If I run `LinearSolve` a second time it returns in 6.3 seconds, due to caching I suppose. `Solve` takes 19 seconds if I run it a second time, so it does not benefit nearly as much from caching. I'm using Mathematica 11.1.

Comment: BTW: `CoefficientArrays[]` is an easier way to get the matrix and vector you need: `{rhs, matrix} = Normal[CoefficientArrays[equations, variables]]; rhs = -rhs;`

Comment: C.E. Thanks so much for the help! I'm running Mathematica 10.0 and in that version LinearSolve never did come back with an answer, even after several hours. Surprisingly, removing the last variable and equation did the trick. Without those, it solved in 8 seconds. And it's easy to compute that last variable from the answer.                                       

J.M. Thanks for the tip. I'll use it!

Comment: Just a thought as I'm no expert. If you think the ZeroTest is the source of the difference use the ZeroTest option to use your own version of ZeroTest, and enforce the two approaches to use the same one, thus checking your hypothesis

Comment: It might be a difference in default setting of `Method` option to `RowReduce`.